# How do we create a Kivy scrollable popup?

Tags: python, kivy

How do we open a popup window with Kivy which can contain any quantity of text, and so must be scrollable ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fully workable example. The initial popup window text is defined in the kv file. A button in the popup demonstrates how the popup text can be set programmatically.

## scrollpopup.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class CustomPopup(Popup):
    contentBox = ObjectProperty()

    def updateScrollablePopupContent(self):
        content = "Hello World\n"
        self.contentBox.content.text = content * 30

class ScrollPopup(BoxLayout):
    popup = None

    def openPopup(self):
        self.popup = CustomPopup(title="Scrollable popup").open()

class ScrollPopupApp(App):
    def build(self): # implicitely looks for a kv file of name kivylistview1111.kv which is
                     # class name without App, in lowercases

        return ScrollPopup()


    def on_pause(self):
        # Here you can save data if needed
        return True


    def on_resume(self):
        # Here you can check if any data needs replacing (usually nothing)
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScrollPopupApp().run()
```

## scrollpopup.kv

```
<ScrollPopup>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    popupButton: popup_button

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        Button:
            id: popup_button
            text: "Open scrollable popup"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: "40dp"
            on_press: root.openPopup()

<CustomPopup>:
    id: popup
    auto_dismiss: False
    contentBox: content_box

    BoxLayout:
        id: content_box
        orientation: "vertical"
        content: content_text

        ScrollView:
            effect_cls: "ScrollEffect" # prevents overscrolling
            Label:
                id: content_text
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text: u"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus odio nisi, pellentesque molestie adipiscing vitae, aliquam at tellus. Fusce quis est ornare erat pulvinar elementum ut sed felis. Donec vel neque mauris. In sit amet nunc sit amet diam dapibus lacinia. In sodales placerat mauris, ut euismod augue laoreet at. Integer in neque non odio fermentum volutpat nec nec nulla. Donec et risus non mi viverra posuere. Phasellus cursus augue purus, eget volutpat leo. Phasellus sed dui vitae ipsum mattis facilisis vehicula eu justo.\n\n Quisque neque dolor, egestas sed venenatis eget, porta id ipsum. Ut faucibus, massa vitae imperdiet rutrum, sem dolor rhoncus magna, non lacinia nulla risus non dui. Nulla sit amet risus orci. Nunc libero justo, interdum eu pulvinar vel, pulvinar et lectus. Phasellus sed luctus diam. Pellentesque non feugiat dolor. Cras at dolor velit, gravida congue velit. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam eu nunc dui, quis sagittis dolor. Ut nec dui eget odio pulvinar placerat. Pellentesque mi metus, tristique et placerat ac, pulvinar vel quam. Nam blandit magna a urna imperdiet molestie. Nullam ut nisi eget enim laoreet sodales sit amet a felis.\n"
                text_size: (self.width-20), None
                line_height: 1.5
                valign: "top"

        Button:
            text: "Update content"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: "40dp"
            on_press: popup.updateScrollablePopupContent()

        Button:
            text: "Close"
            size_hint_y: None
            height: "40dp"
            on_press: root.dismiss()
```

## Result

[image: scrollpopup on Windows]